# Remove/delete jquery-ui dialog box from page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm creating div elements (for entering notes) on the fly using jtemplates which looks something like this -

```
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
      <div id="divNotesMo{$T.index}" title="Notes">
         <textarea id="taNotesMo{$T.index}" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td>
    <div id="divNotesTu{$T.index}" title="Notes">
         <textarea id="taNotesTu{$T.index}" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
    </div>
   </td>
  </table>
```

And I'm making dialog boxes out of them by using `$('divNotesId').dialog` and setting the buttons, etc. When the page loads, all the div elements which has dialogs attached to it are moved to the bottom of the page (removed from the table completely by jquery-ui). I have a requirement to delete the entire row and all of its contents. When I do it, the notes dialogs are not deleted as they are no longer in the table row (they're moved to the bottom of the page). When I build the next new row, the old div id's are conflicting with the new div id's. I'm using jquery-ui-1.8.17.

The markup look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR1pL.png) -

[image]

My question is, how do I delete the dialogs I created on the fly? There are other dialogs on the page that I don't want to delete though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should attach custom data- tag to the dialog matching the table row and then call the dialog [destroy](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-destroy) function when the row is removed.

```
$(<selector>).dialog('destroy');
```

Check my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/cGJrr/4/) which gives you an idea of how to link the `tr` and the `dialog div` and can be later removed when the row is removed.

Comment: Could you please expand on custom data tag? I can see them in the markup but don't know how to select them as they don't seem to have Id's.

Comment: @enigma Check my DEMO code which will give you an idea of how to link tr and dialog and later remove them all together.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I liked how you added the custom tag and also how you chained remove and destroy together. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`destroy`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog/dialog#method-destroy) method

Comment: I saw that in the documentation but it also states that element will be back in its pre-init state. I thought that meant the div is still outside the table. I guess I could try.

Comment: So you want to entirely remove the div from the markup? I thought you just wanted to remove the dialog behavior. If you want to remove the div, just use the `remove` then (http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
(I hope I understood it this time)

Comment: Yes, when I delete the row, I want the div (along with the dialog mark-up) completely gone from the page. When I attach the dialog behaviour, the div gets moved out of the table so it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: The `remove` is probably what you need to use then (after destroy). But keep in mind that this div might 'come back' to the page after a full post back, since the markup on the original file sitting on the server hasn't removed that div. So you might want to add some sort of check for that after a page refresh.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know. The page doesn't have any full page postbacks so I should be good there.

Comment: Thank you very much. You pointed me in the right direction. It worked.